# How to prove Clarkson's inequality?

Tags: analysis, inequality, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

I do not know how to prove one of the four Clarkson's inequalities: let $u,v \in
L^p(\Omega)$, if $1 < p < 2$, then
$$
\bigg\lVert \frac{u+v}{2} \bigg\rVert_p^p + \bigg\lVert \frac{u-v}{2}
\bigg\rVert_p^p \geq \frac{1}{2}\lVert u \rVert_p^p +
\frac{1}{2}\lVert v \rVert_p^p
$$
Could your please help provide a detailed proof? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since both sides are just integrals over $\Omega$, it is enough to prove the inequality for real numbers. This can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118292/clarkson-type-inequality?lq=1).

Alternatively, you can do the following:
\begin{align*}\newcommand\abs[1]{|#1|}
\newcommand\biggnorm[1]{\big\|#1\big\|}
  \abs{x+y}^p + \abs{x - y}^p
  &=
  \biggnorm{
   \begin{pmatrix}
    x+y \\ x-y
   \end{pmatrix}
  }_{p}^p
  \le
  2^{1 - \frac p2}
  \,
  \biggnorm{
   \begin{pmatrix}
    x+y \\ x-y
   \end{pmatrix}
  }_{2}^p
  \\&=
  2
  \,
  \biggnorm{
   \begin{pmatrix}
    x \\ y
   \end{pmatrix}
  }_{2}^p
  \le
  2
  \,
  \biggnorm{
   \begin{pmatrix}
    x \\ y
   \end{pmatrix}
  }_{p}^p
  =
  2 \,
  \big( \abs{x}^p + \abs{y}^p \big)
  .
\end{align*}
Here, one uses the equivalence between the $2$-norm and the $p$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the parallelogram identity.