# how could I prove that $l^p$ is a uniformly convex Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to apply Milman-pettis Lemma to show that $l^p$ is reflexive hoping that Milman-pettis Lemma would do the heavy lifting and was hoping to easily prove  uniform convexity of $l^p$ It turns out I was wrong . I thought triangle inequlality might work but I was wrong and nothing else seems to be working. Any hints on how could I go about doing this? Is the proof hard? Because its been 3 semesters  that I started taking university level Math courses. 
P.S I do know how to show that the canonical embedding of $l^p$ into $(l^p)^{**}$ is surjective.
Please note I am referring to ($1<p<\infty$)
Thanks

Comment: It's a bit boring. You need [Clarkson's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarkson's_inequalities). A relevant post is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/95307/147263) but it does only one case. Luckily, a simple search will supply you more.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato Thank you, this link  is very helpful.